# Get last day of month in python

Tags: python, date

Getting error for December month.

> ValueError: month must be in 1..12

```
def last_day_of_month(ds):
    cur_ds = datetime.strptime(ds, '%Y-%m-%d')
    next_month = datetime(year=cur_ds.year, month=cur_ds.month+1, day=1)
    last_day_month = next_month - timedelta(days=1)
    return datetime.strftime(last_day_month, '%Y-%m-%d')

print last_day_of_month('2016-12-01')
```

Comment: Clearly if the month is December (12), then `month=cur_ds.month+1` would be 13, right? And clearly 13 is not an allowable month, just as the error says?

Comment: Yes, is there way I can handle other than using if condition

Comment: You could use `% 12`, couldn't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a `datetime` with a month of 13. So you have to find a way to fix it. A simple solution is to convert the incremented month to an extra year:

```
# Reduce 12 to 1, 0 and all other #s to 0, #
extrayear, month = divmod(cur_ds.month, 12)
# Add 1 or 0 to existing year, add one to month (which was reduced to 0-11)
next_month = datetime(year=cur_ds.year + extrayear, month=month + 1, day=1)
```

Answer (score 10):

In line 3 `month=cur_ds.month+1` you are giving 13th month which is not valid. If you want to calculate last day of a given month you could also use month range from calendar library.

```
>>import calendar
>>year, month = 2016, 12
>>calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
31
```

Comment: Ooh, solving the real problem directly. I approve. Upvoted. I always forget [the `calendar` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) even exists.

Comment: lol yeah, that's my daily life, writing something up then realizing there is a module for that :/

Comment: Could be worse. Could already exist, but your legacy code base can't use it. Or it's created a month after you finish writing it. I had both, when a 2.7 code base needed to be able to cache stack traces cheaply (so they could be output later if a debug scenario came up). I basically invented [`traceback.StackSummary(lookup_lines=False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.StackSummary) a month before 3.5 released (and of course, I couldn't use `StackSummary` even then, because the codebase was 2.7 and too painful to move to 3.x). Sigh... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in `12` as current month, then adding one to get `next_month`, making it `13`.  Check for the `12` case and set `month=1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I did it.

```
from django.utils import timezone
from calendar import monthrange
from datetime import datetime


current = timezone.now()
firstdayofmonth = current.replace(day=1)
endmonth = monthrange(current.year, current.month)
lastdayofmonth = datetime(current.year, current.month, endmonth[1])
```